# Fill drop-down box with other text field entries

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

We're trying to read 3 text fields and as the user them out they would then be populated in a  drop-down box

Any idea of how this could be done?

We tried following https://docs.gravityforms.com/dynamically-populating-drop-down-fields/

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Do you have an example in the wild of how this should look/work?

Comment: unfortunately nah

Comment: So each value from the Single Line Text field would be an option in the Drop Down? Would there be other options in the Drop Down? Would all three Single Line Text fields always be filled out?

Comment: Each value would only be filled out if the user enters something in them. Once they do then it would show up in the dropdown

Comment: Rats. I don't have a solution for you on this one. Gravity Forms Populate Anything could help you out if the Drop Down would have all 3 options every time via the Live Merge Tags feature... but making the options conditional based on whether the field is filled out or not is beyond its current scope. https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/

Comment: Oh ok darn it. Thanks though.